# Parallel.ForEach doesn't make use of all available thread pool threads

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Why when I run the following example do I only have the Parallel.ForEach run the number of threads equal to the number of cores on my machine?
I thought Parallel.ForEach gives you thread pool threads of which there are approx 1000?

```
            int threads1;
            int threads2;

            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out threads1,out threads2);
            var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 200);
            var po = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(list, po, x =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                });
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You set max degree of parallelism to 100, why would you get 1000 threads? Especially when you only have 200 items in the list? What are the other 800 threads supposed to do? Its worth noting that there is a middle ground to performance vs # of threads, and adding more can decrease performance rather than increase it.

Comment: No, I would expect to get the Parallel.ForEach to process them in 2 batches, of 100 each. I don't expect 1000+ threads.

Comment: That would be a parallelism of 2 (2 threads, 100 work items per thread), I'm still not seeing where the 1000 threads comes into play here? The way you have it now, its 100 "batches" of 2 items each.

Comment: Daniel Moth (TPL) did a nice presentation on why this is a bad idea in the 2008 PDC. https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/pdc2008/TL26

Comment: To answer part of your question, a processor can only process one thread per core, so even if you "batch" them into 100 batches, and it does an even spread between cores, you would get 25 threads per core. Since it can only run 1 thread at a time, it looks like its one thread per core. It should yield in the sleep to the next thread ready to run on that core.

Comment: Ok maybe I've drank too much wine but my goal is to to have the Parallel.ForEach to process in parallel using the most threads that are available. At the moment it is running on 4 at a time, indicating that although there are 1000 thread pool threads available, it is bounded by the number of cores.

Comment: Of course it is, like I said, you can only run one thread per core at a time, it has to context switch to run another thread.

Comment: Ok, if I make MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, it makes no difference. It is no. cores bounded.  It seems it only limits the number of cores I can use. Maybe my question is how do I go about utilising more threads than number of cores if there are 1000+ threads available?

Comment: If you were doing I/O operations where the thread would be put into a state waiting on I/O, you would see more threads being used. MaxDegreeOfParallelism is a *suggestion* about the maximum threads to use, not setting the actual number to use. If you need to use 1000 threads, then you probably need to use something that generates threads manually.

Comment: it seems like MaxDegreeOfParallelism is ignored if you're using async function in the Parallel.ForEach

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` uses managed thread pool to schedule parallel actions. The number of threads is set by `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`. By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the number of processors on a system.

To minimize the usage of system resources, the number of pool threads is kept as low as possible. When all the pool threads are busy executing actions, the scheduler gradually spawns new threads.

The value `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is usually used to prevent `Parallel.For` from scheduling more than the specified number of tasks simultaneously. It is useful in case of long computations when there is no sense of using more threads than the number of cores.

If you modify the code by increasing the sleep time `Thread.Sleep(100000);`, you will see the creation of new threads.

If you call `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);` before `Parallel.ForEach`, you will see all `100` actions started simultaneously.

Comment: Ok I used the default MaxDegreeOfParallelism and then increased the timeout and sure enough it gradually increases the number of threads. My real-world application (unlike the example) uses async/await tasks with database I/O. I'm hoping to get more than 8+ threads (based on cores) to work in parallel as most of it is I/O bound to the database. How can I guarantee it will make most of the 1000+ threads available?

Comment: Set both MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 100 and MinThreads to 100.

Comment: If you are using async/await, consider using `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`.

Answer (score 3):

You will get the best performance if the number of threads doesn't exceed the number of processing cores.

Each core can only process one thread at a time. If there are more threads than cores, the OS has to [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) between threads. Context switching is an expensive operation, you should try to avoid it in multi-threaded applications.

If the operations you perform are IO-bound, you should use `Task`s instead of `Paraller.For`. It's nicely explained on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToParallelBasicsDontBlockYourThreadsMakeAsyncIOWorkForYou.aspx).

The details of `Parallel.For` thread management are explained in details in Andrey Nasonov's answer, so I will not repeat it.

If you want to learn more about threading, TPL and asynchrounous I/O I recommend [CLR via C# book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454)

Comment: Should I then use the ForEach<Async> instead of Parallel.ForEach if the tasks in each loop (4 in my case for each entry in the loop) are async?